# How to frequently stop background image in CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I Created slider using Wordpress plugin called as Slider Revolution, now I am customizing it by CSS.I created small open space in slider where it will show logo of technologies, I am using. apart from that space, I overlay with dark color, But the problem is background image is keep moving without stop. I tried delay but its not working.

In simple word I need slider similar like this: https://www.ripl.com

I created the slider but only problem is that background-image is not stopping.

Here is my current CSS for animation(I did not include overlay because its created in plugin)

```
.slider_1{
        background:repeat-x;
        background-size:26%!important;
        width:5076px!important;
        animation: slide 20s linear infinite!important;
        }


@keyframes slide{
   0%{
       transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     }
   100%{
       transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0);
     }
 }
```

this is current progress from my side:https://siimteq-testing.cloudaccess.host/home_slider/

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
  background-position: fixed
}
```

This is the one way to make it so that your background position doesn't change when you are scrolling.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I am not asking for background fix, I am asking for background image which is moving in slider, you can check the both url which I provided in question.